# Line by line comparison of large text files with python

Tags: python, performance, text-parsing

I am working on some large (several million line) bioinformatics data sets with the general format:

```
chromosomeNumber locusStart locusStop sequence moreData
```

I have other files in this format:

```
chromosomeNumber locusStart locusStop moreData
```

What I need to be able to do is read one of each type of file into memory and if the locusStart of a line of the upper file is between the start and stop of any of the lines in the lower file, print the line to output file 1.  If the locusStart of that line is not between the start and stop of any lines in the bottom file, then print it to output file 2.

I am currently reading the files in, converting them into dictionaries keyed on chromosome with the corresponding lines as values.  I then split each value line into a string, and then do comparisons with the strings.  This takes an incredibly long time, and I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to see your actual code

Comment: honestly I can't understand what refers to terms like _upper file_ and _lower file_

Comment: @neurino - I think upper and lower refer to the code blocks in the OP.
As for the problem I think I would read file 2 first, sort the intervals and then run file 1 line by line - this completely ignores the chromosomeNumber though, so @user680895, please clarify a little?

Comment: So there's exactly one line in both files per chromosome number, and you want to compare only lines with the same chromosome number? And do the files contain the same keys?

Comment: I'm assuming locusStart (and locusStop) is monotonically increasing in both files.  Is it true that locusStart is always larger than locusStop of the previous line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for the lower file (which I assuming has the second format), the only field you are concerned about is 'locusStart'. Since, from your description, you do not necessarily care about the other data, you could make a set of all of the locusStart:

```
locusStart_list = set()
with open(upper_file, 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    tmp_list = line.strip().split()
    locusStart_list.add(tmp_list[1])
```

This removes all of the unnecessary line manipulation you do for the bottom file. Then, you can easily compare the locusStart of a field to the set built from the lower file. The set would also remove duplicates, making it a bit faster than using a list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are going to be doing lots of greater than/less than comparisons, as such I don't think loading your data into dictionaries is going to enhance the speed of code at all--based on what you've explained it sounds like you're still looping through every element in one file or the other.

What you need is a different data structure to load your data into and run comparison operations with. Check out the the [Python `bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html), I think it may provide the data structure that you need to run your comparison operations *much* more efficiently.

---

If you can more precisely describe what exactly you're trying to accomplish, we'll be able to help you get started writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary of the chromosome number is a good idea, as long as you can fit both files into memory.

You then want to sort both lists by locusStart (split the string, convert locusStart to a number--see  [instructions on sorting](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) if you're unsure how to sort on locusStart alone).

Now you can just walk through your lists: if the lower locusStart is less than the first upper locusStart, put the line in file 2 and go on to the next one.  If the lower locusStart is greater than the first upper locusStart then

- While it is also greater than locusEnd, throw away the beginning of the upper list
- If you find a case where it's greater than locusStart and less than locusEnd, put it in file 1
- Otherwise, put it in file 2

This should replace what is now probably an `O(n^2)` algorithm with a `O(n log n)` one.